# yahoo messenger QoS application type

Tags: windows, yahoo, qos, messenger

I am trying to set a QoS rule for yahoo messenger video/voice  call. However I don't know what type of service they are. Are they IGMP, SIP, H323 ,RSTP, ....? 
Or what port range they use?

Answer (score 0):

as far i knw almost all messenger services like skype, msn and gmail uses SIP or RTSP in general and with Audio codec as iBLC.